# How do I create a schema like .dbo in SQL Server [2005]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am creating a database in SQL Server 2005 and cannot remember the "CREATE SCHEMA" statment, if that's it, to create a new schema similar to ".dbo".  I did it last night, but I cannot remember how and cannot find the article.  What I'm trying to accomplish is a database organization like that of the AdventureWorks database where the tables are separated into: Person.Contact, Person.*, HumanResources.blah, Other.Blah, etc.  It's an easy question I'm sure...I just can't remember.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's CREATE SCHEMA
More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx

Comment: No, I just want to separate my database tables with prefixes on the names, similar to that of the MS AdventureWorks sample database: Person.Contact, Person.ContactType... instead of dbo.Contact, dbo.ContactType, etc...it's a one-line tSQL command I cannot remember or find

Comment: AdventureWorks uses schemas. Why are you saying that `create schema Person` isn't it?

Comment: (+1) The syntax you are probably after is: `Create Schema [Person] Authorization [dbo];`

Comment: @Unknown: First create a schema Person (CREATE SCHEMA Person) then create a table Contact using the schema Person (CREATE TABLE Person.Contact etc). Then you'll get Person.Contact